# AngularJs - How does a controller receive $state.go with parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

If this is my state change event:

```
$state.go('MyState', { 'param1':'jimbob', 'param2':37});
```

How does the MyStateCtrl acquire these values?

I tried:

```
   var param1 = $stateParams.param1
   ....


   var param1 = $state.params.param1
   ....
```

each with no success.

**Thanks Outlier:**

```
// state (via json)
"name" : "app.MyStateName",
"url": "/myView123/:param1/:param2",


// controller 1
$state.go('app.MyStateName', {param1: someValue1, param2: someValue2})


// controller 2
var param1 = $stateParams.param1;
var param2 = $stateParams.param2;
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#user-content-url-parameters continue reading all the way down to the $stateParams service and the gotcha. You will need a resolve to do this, if the route doesn't include those params.

Comment: What you have shown is the way you do it. So the issue must be somewhere else, either make a plunker of the issue or show us more code. The stateprovider section in your config would be helpful. You have to have the params available in your state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your state definition, you must have defined your parameters in the value of the url key.

EDIT: To clarify, the following should be in the state definition as one of the key/properties:

```
url: 'myurl/:myparam'
```

However, it's worth noting that this will add myparam to the url. If you don't want the URL to be changed, then you can do the following (newer feature from ui-router):

```
   params: {
          myparam: {
            value:  null,
            squash: true
          }
    }
```

and you can simply get the value by calling $stateParams.myparam in both cases.

The value property sets the default value of the param before it's been passed in. The `squash: true` ensures that the value doesn't affect the url.

For more information:

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider